# Moving the yellow dot in the viewport

Tags: 3d-view

[image]
Hi, how do I move the mesh so the yellow dot in the centre of the viewport is in the centre of the mesh

Answer (score 6):

The yellow dot is the **[origin](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/origin.html?highlight=origin)** of the object.

To move it, select your mesh in object mode and then:
right click or object menu up there--> set origin--> "geometry to origin" or
"origin to geometry" as you want to do

Comment: The mesh becomes distorted when I do that. I have uploaded the file https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/allNvRvv

Comment: The distortion is because you have a Mirror modifier. This modifier uses the origin of your mesh as the origin for mirroring. To fix this, move the 3D Cursor to World Origin (0,0,0) with SHIFT+S. Add an Empty (SHIFT+A), the shape doesn't matter. It will be added at the 3D Cursor to your scene. In the options of the Mirror modifier, you can specify this Empty as 'Mirror Object'. It will be the new origin of the mirror. Because the Empty is at position (0,0,0) the mirror will work symmetrically.